# Multiple nested if(ISNUMBER(FIND... is required

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to do so?

```
Sub test()

r = ActiveSheet.Range("v" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$W2:$W" & r & " ").Formula=
  IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("7212",K2)),"laptop",
     IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("774",K2)),"laptop",
        IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("7745",K2)),"laptop",
           IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("234",K2)),"desktop","NO")))
End Sub
```

I have to apply conditions like this on if condition but I am unable to achieve this.

Kindly anyone help on this

Comment: Doesn't your second condition ("Find 774") make the third condition ("Find 7745") pointless?  If the number 7745 exists, then "Find 774" will find it anyway

Comment: Record a macro and then input the desired formula in the worksheet and you will have your code to work with. Alternatively you can also use `.Find` to achieve what you want. [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: i have to find more than 40 serial numbers  and represent them as laptop and desktop based on refrence with given excel sheet so i have used multiple if  as shown below       Range("$M$2:$M" & r & "").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""12 Rugged 7212"",K2)),""pad-laptop"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""14 5415 Ruggge"",K   but this condition works for only 20 serail numbers

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your formula in double quotes, but in order to do so, you need to double the double quotes within your formula, something like this:

```
Range("$W2:$W" & r & " ").Formula = "IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""7212"",K2)),""laptop"", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""774"",K2)),""laptop"", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""7745"",K2)),""laptop"", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""234"",K2)),""desktop"",""NO"")))"
```

(Sorry for the bad formatting, but VBA does not allow multiline strings)

By the way, I've just edited your formula in order for it to work, but I don't understand your logic: your logic says:

```
If <condition1> 
then "laptop"
else if <condition2>
     then "laptop"
     else if <condition3>
          then "laptop"
          else "desktop"
          end if
     end if
end if
```

Generally, for such a situation, the following logic is used:

```
if <condition1> OR <condition2> OR <condition3>
then "laptop"
else "desktop"
end if
```

This reduces the number of if-loops and makes it more readable.

Comment: And sometimes using a list of the numbers with a lookup can be easier, for example to update the numbers...

Comment: vlookup doesnot help me inthis as  i can find it only particular numbers are present if that serial number is present then give it as desktop and another set of serail numbers which are in predefined in excel based on that laptop or desktop i have to fill it up